# Build and package a maven plugin within another project

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to build a Maven plugin using Eclipse. I need it to be in a project called `Utilities` (contains some other utility tools), i.e. I do not want the plugin to be an Eclipse project all by itself.

The `<packaging>` tag for `Utilities` project in its `POM` is `jar`, while technically a maven plugin needs to be packaged as a `maven-plugin`. Is there any way to get around this? Or must I build the Maven plugin as a separate project?

Comment: Are you trying to build maven plugin and for what purpose? And yes a maven plugin must be build with packagin `maven-plugin` and no there is no way around that...And yes you should build maven plugins as separte projects...

Comment: Well this a requirement from my manager (so that my code will stay in the utilities project.). I will talk to him about this then,,,